# Why is Access form giving me the error message "A column number has been specified more than once in the order list"? The related queries open fine

Tags: forms, ms-access

I'm working on an Access database with a SQL Server back end. Some times when I open a particular form, I get an Error 3146 "Column has been specified more than once in the order by list."

[image]

There are several possible queries that might feed into this form but I checked and ran them all individually and they run fine, so it's something in the form but I'm not sure. Below is a screen shot of the Data Properties window. My hypothesis is that "Order By" property (which I did not populate manually) is not being cleared out when the form closes, and thus when the form is re-opened, that in effect puts in the same columns twice.

[image]

I can temporarily solve the problem by opening up the form and clearing those Filter and Order By fields. That solves it for a while but intermittently it will happen again so there's probably one other thing I'm overlooking. I put in code in the Form close event to set the orderby="" but even that doesn't totally solve it.

Here is the code that opens the form from the main menu (frmProdSched is the form in question)

```
Private Function OpenProdSched(RunQuery, RunCaption)
    DoCmd.OpenForm "frmProdSched", , RunQuery, "", , acNormal
    Forms!frmProdSched.Caption = RunCaption
    gScheduleRptQry = RunQuery
    Me.Refresh
End Function
```

and then the code that is in the Form_Current event

```
Private Sub Form_Current()
    On Error Resume Next
    Dim strForm As String
    Dim strForm1 As String
    Dim strWhere As String

    strForm = "frmSubmittalStatus"
    strForm1 = "frmProdSched"
    strWhere = "StatusJobno = " & Me.JOBNO & ""
    If IsLoaded(strForm) Then
        If Forms(strForm).Filter = strWhere Then
            Forms(strForm1).SetFocus
        Else
            DoCmd.Close acForm, strForm
            DoCmd.OpenForm FormName:=strForm, WhereCondition:=strWhere
            Forms(strForm1).SetFocus
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

I tried adding this code to the Form Close event and it seemed to work most of the time but it still intermittently happens

```
Private Sub Form_Close()
    Me.Filter = ""
    Me.OrderBy = ""
End Sub
```

I'm not sure what to check next. Any ideas?

Comment: Clear the filter in OnOpen event.

Comment: Yeah I think I tried that, but then it gave me an error that the recordset didn't exist or something. I'll try again and report back. Thanks!

Comment: @eric-brandt I used SQL Server as a key word because it does have a SQL Server back end, and the error message included the ODBC Driver for SQL 2017 so I reasonably thought this could be an Access-MSSQL issue.

Comment: Seems to work (at least for now). Thanks!

Comment: @DavidBritz, not an unreasonable guess. But although it’s been years since I worked in Access, I knew from the error it was a form problem, not a server problem. Just cleared the tag so a bunch of SQL Server folks knew they could stand down.